# How to import mongo dump file into OrientDB?

Tags: mongodb, orientdb

I have MongoDB dump file in .bson extension. That i want to import in OrientDB. Should any one know that. Any other way to import DB in OrientDB from MongoDB.

Comment: Could you export it in json?
Here  import from parse that under the hood uses mongodb
http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb-etl.wiki/Import-from-PARSE.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bson` format is a binary format only used by MongoDB. So you first need to export it to a more standard format which you can import into OrientDB. `json` and `csv` are the formats you need (which format to use depends on the complexity of your MongoDB documents, if they have a "flat" structure, use `csv`). See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport

After exporting, you can import the file(s) by the ETL tool of OrientDB.